# Fastest way to write to multiple socket connections

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, sockets, optimization

I am using the following class to accept incoming connections from client applications - using the send function I want to write the same UTFBytes to each client at the same time - is this possible? or if not, what would be the fastest way to write to them sequentially.

```
public class ProjectorClients
{
    private var _serverSocket:ServerSocket;
    private var _clients:Vector.<Socket> = new Vector.<Socket>;

    private function ProjectorClients():void
    {
        _serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
        _serverSocket.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, onConnect)
        _serverSocket.bind(888);
        _serverSocket.listen();
    }

    private function onConnect(e:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void
    {
        trace("Client is connected");
        e.socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
        e.socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onConnectionClosed);
        _clients.push(e.socket);
        trace("Number of connected clients: " + _clients.length);
    }

    public function send(command:String):void
    {
        for each(var clientSocket:Socket in _clients)
        {
            if (clientSocket.connected)
            {
                clientSocket.writeUTFBytes(command);
                clientSocket.flush();
            }
        }
    }

    private function onData(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        trace("data received");
    }   

    private function onConnectionClosed(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Client Socket is Closed");
        for (var i:int = 0; i < _clients.length; i++)
        {
            if (_clients[i] == e.currentTarget)
            {
                _clients.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
        trace("Number of connected clients: " + _clients.length);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you setting up an infrastructure or is this a deployable application?  If this was Java or .Net, I would suggest having the server only write once to a distributed publish-subscribe messaging system like Apache/Kafka.  I don't know if there are any fast-queue solutions for actionScript.

Comment: This is for a deployable as3 only application. thanks for the tip, I will research this for future use.

Comment: What about writing in one loop, then flushing in a second identical loop?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @eSniff, you need a publish subscribe module here. Redis would be a better option as it requires bare minimal steps to set up. The incoming connections will subscribe to the queue and you can publish the data, so that all the client receive it the same time. Please refer to the link below for better understanding.

http://redis.io/topics/pubsub