# Socket programming in Flash and AIR...two clients, one server. Listen on two ports or one?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, air

I have a server that will be getting information from two clients. These 3 machines live on the same local network (connected to same hub). Both clients will be constantly sending x,y information to the server.

I'm trying to figure out which approach is better:

**Approach A**

Server listening on one port. Clients connect to same port. I would try to distinguish data from each by encoding client info into the data.

**Approach B**

Server listens on two ports. Client A always connects to first port, Client B always connects to the second port. I would know, based on the port, who sent what.

Comment: Just one port will do.

you can reference from this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383977/fastest-way-to-write-to-multiple-socket-connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one port. When a client connects it gets it's own Socket instance so you know from what client data is received all the time. If you have 2 distinct roles for clients use some simple authorization when a client is connected like "hey! I'm client with role A!".

Answer (score 2):

Approach A : when a client is connecting to the socket server, have the server return an id and increment it, so both clients have ids. Then when you send the data (x and y) send as well the id.

Comment: I agree that approach A is better than B, but the client ID isn't needed. As per valyard's answer, there is normally separate socket instances on the server communicating on the same port. This is managed by the underlying socket system (remember that the clients have unique IPs to distinguish them already). Approach B should only be considered if you are handling so many connections that a single port cannot manage them all. ~64K minus the reserved ports.